# formArrayName must be used with a parent formGroup directive

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm getting an error: `formArrayName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance`. I'm not sure what am I doing wrong.
I would like the FormGroup to iterate several time(using `ngFor`), and thought using `formArrayName` would be the answer.

> HTML:

```html
<div formArrayName = "PaymentArray" *ngFor = "let meshalem of paymentForm.get('PaymentArray').controls;let i =index;">
    <div [formGroup]="i">
        <div class="row box-border" >
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 pull-right required">
                <label class="control-label">מספר ת.ז. משלם</label>
                <input #PidField name="id_pay" id="id_pay" formControlName="id_pay" class="form-control input-lg"
                    maxlength="9" (input)="searchChange($event.target.value)" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> .ts File:

```js
  paymentForm = this.fb.group({
    PaymentArray: this.fb.array([])
  })
  
  
  
  getPaymentList()
  {
   
        this._adminService.getPayment(this.id).subscribe(res => {
            if(res.isSuccess)
            {
                this.PaymentList = res.data ;
                this.PaymentList.forEach((pays) => {
                        this.meshalemArray = this.paymentForm.get('PaymentArray') as FormArray;
                        this.meshalemArray.push(this.fb.group({
                            id_pay:[pays.id_pay,Validators.compose([Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$"), Validators.required])],
                            numberRooms:[pays.numberRooms],
                            sum: [pays.sum],
                            paymentMethod:[pays.paymentMethod],
                            credit:[pays.credit],
                        }))  
                        
                })
            }
            else
            {
              //TODO
            }
        })
    
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Error is causing because you are not using `FormArray` inside `FormGroup`. Just wrap the `FormArray` inside the `FormGroup`:-

```
<form [formGroup]="paymentForm">
  <div formArrayName = "PaymentArray" *ngFor = "let meshalem of paymentForm.get('PaymentArray').controls;let i =index;">
    <div [formGroup]="i">
      <div class="row box-border" >
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 pull-right required">
          <label class="control-label">מספר ת.ז. משלם</label>
          <input #PidField name="id_pay" id="id_pay" formControlName="id_pay" class="form-control input-lg"
                 maxlength="9" (input)="searchChange($event.target.value)" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And I think `<div [formGroup]="i">` should be eigther `<div [formGroupName]="i">` or `<div [formGroup]="meshalem">`

Comment: then I'm getting an error: `ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

       Example:

       
    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>`

Comment: ok. your update did the work.
What is the difference between `formGroup` and `formGroupName` ?

Comment: @YanivEliav `formGroup` needs the actual instance of the formGroup whenever `formGroupName` needs the name of the instance..!